# Processing button events

Tags: java, events, processing

I'm trying to implement sort of a popup window to display information about authors in given country i managed to do this. I load my interactive map and I do get a popup message when I left click on the country. However soon as I release the button, the popup disappears.

I want to popup that is drawn to stay there until I right click on right click it should disappear.

So I'm having problems implementing it so that popup that is displayed in mouseReleased() method stays drawn.

```
// Import libaries
import org.gicentre.geomap.io.*;
import org.gicentre.geomap.*;

// Instance new GeoMap
GeoMap geoMap;
PImage bgImage;

void setup()
{
  size(1280, 768);

  // Load background pattern img and implement AA for shapes
  bgImage = loadImage("bg.jpg");
  smooth();

  // New GeoMap instance
  geoMap = new GeoMap(this);

  // Load map shape
  geoMap.readFile("world");
}

void draw()
{
  // Fill ocean with bg image
  background(bgImage);

  // Change stroke color
  stroke(255, 255, 255);

  // Fill the continents color and draw the map
  fill(26, 117, 181);
  geoMap.draw();

  // Get country id by mouse location
  int countryID = geoMap.getID(mouseX, mouseY);

  // Offgrid: -1
  if (countryID != -1)
  {
    // Listen for mouse event and trigger action
    mouseReleased(countryID);
    // Color the select country
    fill(14, 96, 166);
    geoMap.draw(countryID);
  }
}

void mouseReleased(int countryID)
{
  // Act on left clicks
  if(mouseButton == LEFT)
  {
    println(getCountryName(countryID, 3));

    noStroke();
    fill(255, 192);
    rect(0, 0, width, 20);

    if (countryID != -1)
    {
      String name = getCountryName(countryID, 3);
      fill(0);
      textAlign(LEFT, CENTER);
      text(name, 0, 0, width, 20);
    }

  }
}


// Returns country name by id
String getCountryName(int id, int offset)
{
  // Get country name for query
  // getString(int id, int offset), int id: country id, int offset: 
  // Example USA
  // offset 0 = Country Code -> 257
  // offset 1 = Country Short Tag -> US
  // offset 2 = Country Short Name -> USA
  // offset 3 = Official Name -> United States
  String name = geoMap.getAttributes().getString(id, offset);

  return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your draw function repeats continuously, but you are only drawing when the lmb is pressed. As soon as it is released, the next call to draw will draw over your popup.

One way to solve this would be to store a variable (say "shouldDraw") to tell you whether to draw or not.  When the lmb is pressed, you would set this to true, and when the rmb is pressed, you would set it to false.  Then instead of checking for LEFT, you would check shouldDraw.

I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, but there may be an onClick method or similar, which would be a more appropriate place than draw for changing you shouldDraw variable.

This will make the label change if you click and then move the mouse. If you want the same text to remain, you could instead store a String and set it to null when there is nothing to draw.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function called mouseReleased that takes no parameter in Processing. You are overloading it intentionally? 
Any way this is a bit confusing. I would do some thing like this:

(pseudocode)

```
void setup() {
 // stuff
 }

    void draw()
{

if (id != -1)
  drawPopup(id);

}

void mouseReleased() //default method called when mouse is released
 {
 if (mouseButton == LEFT)
 id = geoMap.getID(mouseX, mouseY);
}

void drawPopup(int id){
 println(getCountryName(countryID, 3));

noStroke();
fill(255, 192);
rect(0, 0, width, 20);

if (countryID != -1)
{
  String name = getCountryName(id, 3);
  fill(0);
  textAlign(LEFT, CENTER);
  text(name, 0, 0, width, 20);
}
```

}
This way there will always be a popup after the first, or you need to reset the id to -1 in proper condition or add the boolean suggested by mdgeorge. But usually it is better not to do draw stuff inside mouse functions. Things get easier to control.
edit: I should have pointed that there is also built in [void mousePressed() and void mouseClicked()](http://processing.org/reference/) and some more check the reference.